# c# check if another instance of App is running on another pc

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am building a small CMS in c# that allows the user to edit and update report information. i.e. Report Name, Author, Description etc. and then saves to a JSON file.

This JSON file is then used in a Local WebApp as a front end.

Please note that this is an internal application and everyone using the CMS would have access to the same network drive.

When a user opens the CMS on PC #1, I'd like to have a prompt to the user that tries to open the CMS on PC #2 and emulates Excel's 'Read Only' feature and thus disables some functionality until the other instance has been closed.

**Question: What's the most elegant way to do this, in your experience?**

I have one idea:

When the CMS is opened on PC #1, it creates a file called isopen.txt or something similar then deletes the file when closed. When the CMS is opened on PC #2 it would check to see if the file exists and then decides the 'permission' state the CMS will be ran. This 'Check' method could be called after every 'x' seconds and then prompt the user that the CMS is now able to enter the editable state.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go and would love for some experienced C# developers input!

Comment: Which C# object do you use to read the JSON? (FileStream or StreamReader, etc.)

Comment: I've used StreamReader. This is then Deserialized by using the Newtonsoft.Json Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `FileStream` and then initalize the `StreamReader` from it:

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(@"path\file.json", FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
{
   string json = r.ReadToEnd();
   //your subsequent json operations
}
```

The `FileShare.Read` allows read-only access to the file while you are working on it within the `using` scope.

Also, this way is beneficial, because you don't have to manualy close the stream, it gets disposed of when you exit the `using`.